# Docker build error /bin/sh: 1: apt-get: not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker

i tried to build docker image but have this problem
Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Noon qop.box@gmail.com

RUN apt-get update && \ apt-get -y git 

CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `install`. Try `apt-get install -y git`

Comment: The backslash isn't necessary when the line is on one command. Is the error message complaining about `apt-get` or `<space>apt-get` (can't get a real space inside backquotes)?

Comment: You are right @chepner, @Noon you should use `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git`. It worked for me.

Comment: Try using another plain text editor.

Answer (score 5):

The extraneous backslash is causing the space preceding `apt-get` to be treated literally, rather than just separating the command name from `&&`. The means you are trying to run a command named `<space>apt-get`. Just omit the backslash.

```
# And add the install command to the second call to apt-get
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

The backslash is only necessary if you want to split the `RUN` command across two lines, like

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y git
```

where the backslash acts as a line continuation in the Dockerfile; it's not part of the command itself.

Answer (score 1):

As @tgogos answered in comment, you can try

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

But if you want to use multi-line, you can also use like this

```
RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y git \
   && <other command under RUN> \
   && <and so on>
```

And @chepner is also right about multi-line style

Answer (score 1):

A similar error could occur if you are on a different Unix distribution. In my case I changed `apt-get` to `apk` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using *conda install -c anaconda* git worked for me